# how to access the content of a tuple inside a list in haskell?

Tags: haskell, tuples, list-comprehension

I'm trying to do a very simple example to try to get how Haskell works and I have the following doubt:

I have this code:

```
associated :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> [b]
associated a tuple = [b  | b  <- tuple, a==fst(tuple) ]
```

I want to know how to access the content of the tuples of the lists to make comparisons. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the list and take the `fst` values:

```
associated :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> [b]
associated a tuplst = map snd $ filter (\(x,_) -> a == x) tuplst
```

Or use similar behaviour comprehension:

```
associated a tuplst = [b | (a', b) <- tupls, a == a']
```

You can pattern match the tuples inside the comprehension with `(a', b) <- tupls`, this will unpack the values into `a'` and 'b' and then just add the filter `a == a'` too while just taking `b`.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm having a hard time with the sintax.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure this is a homework question - the original function signature was probably `Eq a => a -> [(a,b)] -> [b]`

Comment: Umm another question. If I wanted to do it using list comprehension then how it would be?

Comment: @Luis you cant use list comprehension over tuples.

Comment: It is, but I don't want the exact answer, just examples to see how it works because I really dont understand and everything that I see online doesn't help me

Comment: ugh yeah sorry!! I meant that question for the [(a,b)] type

Comment: @Luis, change the question and ill update the answer for that type

Comment: ok I feel really dumb right now, it was very simple in the end... Thanks alot

Comment: Shouldn't you `map snd` instead of `map fst`?